# Extracting names of POIs from multiple point feature to polygon

Tags: arcmap, polygon, point, attribute-joins, spatial-join

[image]I have many point features and polygons, The point file contains names of the POIs, what I want to do is, through spatial join I want to extract the names from the point file to the polygon, the only problem is that there are many instances in which there are 3 points inside a single polygon and by doing 'One to Many', the algorithm is making duplicates of the polygons and storing each in those duplicates, I want to populate a single field or different fields but only in one single feature. So if there are 2 or 3 points falling under one polygon I wish to have names like:

```
Name 1: A  
Name 2: B   
Name 3: C   
or Name: A,B,C.
```

Comment: Just set the merge rule to join in the output field that will hold then names. That's in the field mapping parameter of the tool.